# Struggling to apply algebra to an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm stuck in the following problem. I feel there may be an elegant solution that's avoiding me, as it's obvious choosing $a$ such that $x-ay$ orthogonal to y will minimize $x-ay$, but I'm getting stuck in the algebra. Here's the problem.

let $||\cdot||$ be a norm on $V$, derived from an inner product, let $x,y\in V$ and suppose $y\ne0$. Show that the scalar $a_0$ that minimizes $||x-ay||$ is $a_0=\langle x,y\rangle/||y||^2$, and that $x-a_0y$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

Once I have the first part, the second part is trivial to show.

I've tried expanding $\langle x-ay,x-ay\rangle$, but I haven't seen any obvious solution emerge, besides being rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding $||x-ay||^2 = \langle x-ay, x-ay\rangle$ results in
$$
||x||^2 - 2a\langle x,y\rangle + a^2||y||^2,
$$
which is a quadratic function of $a$.  Since the coefficient of $a^2$ is positive, it has a minimum.  The derivative with respect to $a$ is
$$
2a||y||^2 - 2\langle x,y\rangle,
$$
which is zero when $a = \langle x,y\rangle/||y||^2$.

Comment: Oh. I feel a bit silly then, thank you.